# How to configure Guake toggle with Super + `?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, guake

I would like to configure Guake toggle shortcut with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. I can enter this key combination in the Guake settings (it appear as "Super+`"), but it doesn't have any effect: using this combination doesn't work. Using the combination in some editor produces tilde symbol.

I've checked all configured shortcuts in the Keyboard settings, but didn't find any which would use the same combination, so it should not be an issue with overlapping shortcuts.

Does anyone know how to configure it the way I want it?

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of many Linux distros now use Wayland instead of X11 for GUI service, and as such no shortcut for guake works at all (at the time of writing) not even the default one.

The workaround is to manually set up the keyboard shortcut in Gnome and not in the Guake app itself.

[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDCEh.png)

Go to Gnome Setting app -> keyboard -> view and customize shortcuts.

Go to custom shortcuts at the bottom and a custom shortcut and assign it to `guake-toggle`

Also, this shortcut is used for something else by default and you may want to remove that shortcut first.

Search in shortcuts for "switch windows" and disable the one using super+` by clicking it and hitting backspace.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the guake window will always show and never hide when I press F12 configured in ubuntu 22.04 global shortcuts.

Apparently, when it is shown and I press F12, it instantly hides before these commands are able to detect it is shown: guake, guake -t, guake --is-visible, guake-toggle or even any script I code...
I guess it is because of some option I configured like auto hide on lost focus probably...

So anyway, I have to use this to make it work properly (put it in a script file like `guakeToggleWindow.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
strFlStatus="/tmp/`basename $0`.tmp"
if((`cat "$strFlStatus"`==1));then #this may never happen now with the wait hide below
    guake --hide
    echo 0 >"$strFlStatus"
else
    guake --show
    echo 1 >"$strFlStatus"
    while true;do
        if((`guake --is-visible`==0));then #waits it hide by any means
            echo 0 >"$strFlStatus"
            break
        fi
        sleep 0.333
    done
fi
```

this works always (different from previous script version)